# Using MVC Controller to replace .ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need a controller to handle file uploads.  Is it possible to just have a handler print text directly to the page rather than return view(); ?

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["fileData"];

            Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            string userID = userGuid.ToString();

            string targetLocation = "D:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\RTDOTNETMEMBER\\audio\\songs\\mp3\\" + userID + "\\" + file.FileName;

            file.SaveAs(targetLocation);

            Response.Write("Testing");
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little more, you can return text with return Content("bla"), but it probably isn't the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed is what I was looking for.  I'm a little new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using **ContentResult** will do the job:

```
return new ContentResult() { 
    Content = "Testing", 
    ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32, 
    ContentType = "text/plain" 
};
```

Comment: Gorans comment above would be a bit more standard syntax referencing this.Content directly on the controller to return the ContentResult

Answer (score 0):

Just change the return type of your action method to string and return a string. It would look somethig like this:

> ```
>     public string ReturnString()
>     {
>         return "Just a string";
>     }
> ```